# Is there a handy way to figure out whether an Object implements

Tags: c#, reflection, data-binding

I'm trying to figure out if there is any builtin routines or classes in the .NET framework that could provide a convenient way to test whether a collection implements among the following interfaces and hence hook to the relevant events, if any:

- `IEnumerable`
- `IList`
- `ICollection`
- `IBindingList`
- `IEnumerable <T>`
- `IList <T>`
- `ICollection <T>`
- `IRaiseItemChangedEvents`
- `INotifyCollectionChanged`

Mostly for data-binding purposes...

I can go with a lot of reflections (e.g. IsAssignableFrom) but since it seems to be a pretty common scenario, I was wondering if there was anything already done in that regard.

[EDIT]
Seems my question is too vague or poorly phrased, my bad. As I indicated a bit later in one of my comments I was more looking for a way to provide a centralized databinding way of doing, could be interested to make UI-agnostic, seems MS provides internally some tooling such as:
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewDataConnection.cs,68950bc360ed4e45,references
but nothing is public.

Right now, my approach is to wrap up everything with a kind of BindingSource equivalent and check whether the object passed to the constructor implements any of the interface I am willing to hook up with.

Comment: Something beyond saying `if (myCollection is IList)`?

Answer (score 2):

You could alternatively to the `is` operator of the previous answer use the `as` Operator:

```
var IEnumerable myIEnumerableObject = unknownObject as IEnumerable;
if(myIEnumerableObject != null)
{
    myIEnumerableObject.SomeEvent += SomeEventHandler;
}
```

Comment: With the first code example (as it is now) you do not know either if the eventhandler has been added. You can add a boolean or something...

Comment: Sure, but you can add an else and try to parse to the next interface from the list or add a boolean as you said in the if statement. This is not possible in the second approach.

Comment: Your second example won't compile in C#6.  You can't use the null-propagation operator on the left side of assignments like that (you're also missing parentheses).

Comment: You're right I removed that part from the answer. Thx

Comment: Already done something similar but was more expecting MS providing a wrapper doing the job instead of reinventing the wheel. 
Sadly seems there is nothing available out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @aquinas, you can use [the .Net `is` keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) to check whether or not an instance of an object implements a specified interface.

Example:

```
if (unknownObject is IEnumerable)
{
    foreach (var obj in uknownObject)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to do some casting or conversion here, the code as-is won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the specific interface from the collection e.g.

```
if(CurrentCollection.GetType().GetInterface("IInterfaceName")!=null)
{
   // Implements interface IInterfaceName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should create your own extension method:

```
public static class CustomCollectionExtension
{
    public static bool AddEvent(this IList myList, EventHandler e)
    {
        // Do Some Stuff
        return true;
    }

    public static bool AddEvent(this ICollection myCollection, EventHandler e)
    {
        // Do Some Stuff
        return true;
    }

    // And so on...

}
```

Then, in your application it will be easy to use it, without knowing the type of your collection with something like:

```
dataContainer.AddEvent(evt);
```

Comment: I was more thinking about the mechanisms leveraged by the datasource-like databinding of some controls whether it is with WPF (DataGrid.ItemsSource) or Winforms (DataGridView.DataSource), I guess my best bet is still to check out the MS code, e.g. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridView.cs